# Eclipse (Mars) keeps closing, no warning error file created

Tags: eclipse

I am doing my end of year project for uni and eclipse has started closing down without warning which is causing me to lose some work every time.  I have been working on this project for the past two weeks with no issues until today!

I am on windows 7, Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600 I have changed my work space as I read this could be corrupt however I am still having the problem.  I need to get my project finished by Friday which is an applet so was really hoping someone could shed a bit light on what the problem could be.  Many Thanks!

It has crashed four times in the past hour and it creates a log file called hs_errpid(random number here: 7248).txt which contains a lot text which I fully don't understand.  The start of it is as follows:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d5dd977, pid=7248, tid=6088

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 Compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  0x000000006d5dd977
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

p.s I am using sqlite and had to download a Jar for it to work called sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar and also JCalendar.-1.4.jar

Comment: I completely uninstalled all programs which have anything to do with Eclipse such as the JDK etc, reinstalled them all made a new work space and imported my project.  All was fine for about an hour and then it closed again losing about another 20mins worth of work.  I don't understand I have no new sortware or hardware, it is just happening out of the blue.

Comment: Having the same error; did you make any progress on this?

Comment: I found it was due to the windowbuilder addon.  Whenever i switch to that and it built the code it would cause it to crash however, not always instantly.  I found once I built the code I just restarted Eclipse and I didn't use the builder again unless I REALLY needed to.  Do not know of any fix.